# how to script a button that saves the user's websites browsing history in livecode

Tags: livecode

I need your help

I am programming a URL browsing site when you long press on the button named site01 it will enable you to type a URL, and I need your help in how to script a button that saves the user's websites browsing history and is there a way to know that the website URL which the user has entered is active and correct, I am still a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out **browserNavigateComplete** in the Dictionary. This may enable you to manually record the navigation changes inside the browser object. (i.e. add the URL to a list of sites, or an array for example.)

Also check out the lessons on LiveCode's site, such as: http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4069/l/22836-how-do-i-use-the-browser-control